# Is it possible to show a spinner or autocomplete textview on popup window?

Tags: android, popup, android-dialog

How to show a spinner or autocomplete textview on a popup window?
In my application i need to show a popup window which contains spinner or a custom dropdown list. If it is not possible over a popup window, what is the alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes its possible. you need to design your `custom layout` and call that layout in popup window

For suppose this is my `pop up` code.

```
 private void showPopUp()
 {
    final AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    helpBuilder.setTitle("");

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View PopupLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.jobselection, null);
    helpBuilder.setView(PopupLayout);

    final AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
    helpDialog.show();

    spn =   (Spinner)PopupLayout.findViewById(R.id.spn);
    caneclbtn = (ImageButton)PopupLayout.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
    selectallbtn    =   (ImageButton)PopupLayout.findViewById(R.id.selectBtn);
    clearallbtn     =   (ImageButton)PopupLayout.findViewById(R.id.clearallBtn);
    jobentries      =   (Button)PopupLayout.findViewById(R.id.entries);

    jobList         =   (ListView)PopupLayout.findViewById(R.id.list);

    //ur code here. You can add your spineer with items.
}
```

In this block you can write what you require. good luck

Comment: and a spinner on popup window? how?

Comment: thanks for your answer. this works fine but the dialog size is limited. is it possible to change the size of dialog?

Comment: there is a facility in android that we can show any page as dialog. so first of all create page in and add android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" in manifest to that activity. and then it will big size.

Comment: In this config, how do you setup the listener--especially for the spinner and the OK button?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to show spinner on popup the u have to set the android:spinnerMode="dialog" for the spinner.. and yes you have to make a custum layout for the popup and inflate it.

here is my code :

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater  = (LayoutInflater)IOStatusActivity.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)    
final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupai, null);  

final PopupWindow popupWindowDi = new PopupWindow(popupView,  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  

final   TextView txtReadVal = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.lblPopUpAiReadFrmPLC);
final   EditText txtExpVal = (EditText)popupView.findViewById(R.id.txtPopUpAiExpVal);
Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnPopUpAiCancle);                          
btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
popupWindowDi.dismiss();
}});`
```

you can add ur spinner as i added the button and edit text. hope it help.

Comment: here is the example code for inflating your popup layout: LayoutInflater layoutInflater  = (LayoutInflater)IOStatusActivity.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
       final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupai, null);  
       final PopupWindow popupWindowDi = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: here popupai is the layout of popup that you can create on xml. 
IOStatusActivity is the name of activity in wich you want to show the popup.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the spinner works fine with android:spinnerMode="dialog"on a popup window. how can i show a autocomplete textview?

Comment: because i customize autocomplete textview to create a dropdown list.

Comment: what is stopping you u do add  autocomplete textview ?? do you get any error ??

Comment: add autocomplete textview in xml do same as done in the code with normal textview.

Comment: autocomplete textview uses popup window to show its dropdown list, and its not possible to show a popup over another popup.

Comment: yes its true.. because the activity is in pause and not actully running. better to avoid the autocomplete textview and try to search a way around.

Comment: one more thing if you use textview in popup set:  android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" other wise ur activity ma crash. personal experience.

Comment: the above example(by Ram kiran) is of  AlertDialog.Builder its different from popup. but its a good way around.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use dialog (`android.app.Dialog`) to implement `AutoCompleteTextView`. In my opinion it's not possible to add  `AutoCompleteTextView` in `PopupWindow` (you will get an exception). You can add `Spinner` in `PopupWindow`. You can implement both if you are using dialog instead of popup.